# how many user (max limit) can access my app in Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

currently I am using free Persoanl Heroku plan.
Can I know how many users can access my app ? I mean what is the limit of users which can access and purchase book from the app at the same time.
https://ranjenbookstore.herokuapp.com/ ?
This is a bookstore where user can purchase and add items to shopping cart.
Can I know if there is limit. How many users can access at same time if I upgraded to Hobby plan?

Answer (score 1):

The only sure way to know is to subject your app to a load test (for example, using loader.io. They have an addon on Heroku).

You can also calculate your hard upper limit by multiplying the number of your web instances (`heroku ps web`) by your concurrency level (max number of processes and/or threads). This is usually set in `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable.